# Splitting big base 64 data crashes in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, split, base64

Hey I'm trying to `split` a 400mb file (buffer turned into a string) into 4 chunks. NodeJS crashes with this error:

"invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

```
const base64Data = Buffer.from(buffer, "binary").toString("base64");

console.log(base64Data.length); // length = 436875456

console.log(base64Data.split("")); // results in crash
```

I understand the error, I just can't find a solution to create an array from the long string and divide it into chunks.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you. You just need to add [1]. Let me know if you still have problem.

```
console.log(base64Data.split("")[1]);
```

For example here result is a 64bit data.

```
var result = 
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAAAAABX3
VL4AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEA mpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3gYSDCUgSze0AAAAAA5JREFUCNdjrGJgYmAAAAJ0AH4SDHVIAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

alert(result.split(',')[1]);
alert(result.substr(result.indexOf(',') + 1));
```